# How to launch pip-Win command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

How do I launch the pip-Win command line? I know, for most people, they would simply answer this:

```
pip install <package>
```

At least, that's what other questions on this site, and search engines, say.

However, I am looking for a way to actually **open** the pip-Win app and actually **use** the PyInstaller package to compile Python scripts.

Is there any way to install/activate/open pip-Win command line?

Comment: This isn't very clear. Could you provide more specifics in to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to use PyInstaller, but it said to search for the pip-Win app. However, there was no app installed and I could not use pip-Win app (or whatever it is called)

Comment: If you have `pyinstaller` installed just use windows cmd. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html